# {{ form }} versus {{ form.as_table }} in Django template

Tags: html, django, forms, django-forms, django-templates

> Style A

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{ form.as_table }} <!-- Notice this -->
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

> Style B

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{ form }} <!-- Notice this -->
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

What's the difference between style A and style B? After some simple experiments, I found that their [HTML output](https://gist.github.com/sunqingyao/1bf6c254effb5e89722892466fe85940) is identical.

I've read the [document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#as-table), and it seems to imply that these two styles are interchangeable, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Did the below answer helped you to resolve your issue?

Comment: @nik_m I expected an explanation from Django's source code level, but your answer is OK.

Comment: I believe it's more verbose to write it as `as_table()`. That's all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right.

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#as-table):

> Finally, `as_table()` outputs the form as an HTML . **This is exactly the same as print.** In fact, when you print a form object, it calls its `as_table()` method behind the scenes

So, as you said, *these two styles are interchangeable*.